# Send email whenever a specific cell contains a specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadhsheet ("Trigger") in a Google Workbook with three columns:

- Column A: Email address
- Column B: Email text
- Column C: cell which either contains "yes" or "no"

The values for these columns start in row 2 and so far I need a solution for only this single row.

Whenever the value in cell `C2` is `"yes"` (the calculation here is based on a current stock price) I want to send an email to the email account in `A2` with the text in `B2` and the subject to be `"Price has been reached? ==" & C2`

What I have so far (I am very new to this but have some experience in VBA) is this:

```
 function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "Price has been reached? ==";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

This works in sending an email but does not take the value in `C2` into account. How can I achieve this?

Also I am wondering how to code that this script should only be linked to spreadsheet "Trigger" and not to other sheets in this workbook?

Once this works I can define a proper trigger within the Script Editor and then think about how to make this work for more than one row.

Comment: So just to be clear the main question is about setting up the trigger? What makes c2 become yes? Is it a formula based on the price? How do you get the price?

Comment: The main question is how to code that only if c2 becomes "yes" an email is sent. Yes it is a formula based on a price using +Googlefinance("PG","price"), but I omitted these columns in the description as only the calculated value in c2 is important

Comment: That actually is quite important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some functions such as `GOOGLEFINANCE` do not cause onEdit or onChange to trigger.

You'll need to create a time based trigger that checks frequently (up to once a minute)

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Trigger");  // To only handle the trigger sheet
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    if (row[2] === "Yes") {       // Trigger only if Column C is "Yes"
      var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
      var message = row[1];       // Second column
      var subject = "Price has been reached? ==" + row[2]; // Add "Yes" although by your trigger logic it will always say yes in the email
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

And then set the trigger in the script editor.

Comment: Thanks, however I get a code TypeError: Cannot find function getSheetByName in object SpreadsheetApp. And then it highlights the line "var sheet = ..." ... What is happening? I have double-checked the sheetname but the name is "Trigger" so I am wondering why it cannot find that

Comment: Sorry, it should be `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Trigger");`

Comment: Probably, I am blind but where is the different in "var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Trigge‌​r");" to "var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Trigger");  ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I didn't notice that you already edited your original post. I will try this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this works terrific. I will now try if I can manage to adjust this script so that it is applicable for a number of rows.