# automatic send email based on cell value & adjust with previous Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to auto send email based Column D "Today"
to Email on Column A with Subject of COlumn B and Body of Columnn C

[image]

I found a script quite similar to my condition, but it only send to a static email
[Script Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903193/send-email-whenever-a-specific-cell-contains-a-specific-value)

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email");  // To only handle the trigger sheet
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    if (row[2] === "Today") {       // Trigger only if Column C is "Yes"
      var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
      var message = row[1];       // Second column
      var subject = "Bday ==" + row[2]; // Add "Yes" although by your trigger logic it will always say yes in the email
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

And is it possile to make it compatible with my previous script
[Link Source](https://gist.github.com/Max-Makhrov/060c21da4f280b6faac82337dadb16e5)

this script about Dynamic Dependent Drop Down Lists

```
function onEdit(event) 
{
  var maxRows = false;
    
  // Change Settings:
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  var TargetSheet = 'Main'; // name of sheet with data validation
  var LogSheet = 'Data1'; // name of sheet with data
  var NumOfLevels = 4; // number of levels of data validation
  var lcol = 2; // number of column where validation starts; A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var lrow = 2; // number of row where validation starts
  var offsets = [1,1,1,2]; // offsets for levels
  //                   ^ means offset column #4 on one position right.  
  // var maxRows = 500; // to set the last row of validation; delete this row if not needed

  
  // =====================================================================================
    
  SmartDataValidation(event, TargetSheet, LogSheet, NumOfLevels, lcol, lrow, offsets, maxRows);
  
  // Change Settings:
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  var TargetSheet = 'Main'; // name of sheet with data validation
  var LogSheet = 'Data2'; // name of sheet with data
  var NumOfLevels = 7; // number of levels of data validation
  var lcol = 9; // number of column where validation starts; A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var lrow = 2; // number of row where validation starts
  var offsets = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]; // offsets for levels
  // var maxRows = 500; // to set the last row of validation, delete this row if not needed
  // =====================================================================================  
  SmartDataValidation(event, TargetSheet, LogSheet, NumOfLevels, lcol, lrow, offsets, maxRows);

  
}



function SmartDataValidation(event, TargetSheet, LogSheet, NumOfLevels, lcol, lrow, offsets, maxRows) 

..... Etc etc
```

Sorry the script is so long, i got warning "your post mostly code"
i just post some of it here and you can check full script on[Link Source](https://gist.github.com/Max-Makhrov/060c21da4f280b6faac82337dadb16e5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the script as such to check the rows and send email based on value of column D:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email");  // To only handle the trigger sheet
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:D
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    if (row[3] === "Today") {       // Trigger only if Column D is "Today"
      var emailAddress = row[0];
      var subject = row[1];
      var message = row[2];
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

To use this in a trigger similar to your second script you need to create an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and specify the function name. For example, if you want to trigger the sending every 24 hours:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every 24 hours.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmails')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(24)
      .create();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, i put this on my gsheet and 2-3 days to evaluate. i'll report here with result

Comment: Sir the email doesnt send, i copy paste your script on top of Dynamic Dependent Drop Down Lists script and allowed permission it asked

Comment: This is the Gsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A9zec2A1cp9KSPWrhFsLRjgzwd6LW8yovMlnNMaTfE0/edit?usp=sharing, it only Works when i Press "run" on script. how to make automaticly triggered?

Comment: It automatically triggers every 24 hours / 1 day. If you want to test the trigger you can change the duration to like every 5 minutes as such ````everyMinutes(5)````

Comment: thankyou so much sir, i adjust the trigger as my need