# trigger for automactly send email twice a day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to make trigger run auto send email twice a day even do not open spreedsheet

This script is for sending email onsheet "Emai"
Col A what email to send to
Col B subject
Col C message

[Link Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69485092/automatic-send-email-based-on-cell-value-adjust-with-previous-script/69485889#69485889)

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email");  // To only handle the trigger sheet
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:D
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    if (row[3] === "Today") {       // Trigger only if Column D is "Today"
      var emailAddress = row[0];
      var subject = row[1];
      var message = row[2];
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
}

function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every 24 hours.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmails')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(5)
      .nearMinute(30)
      .everyDays(1)
      .create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmails')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(18)
      .nearMinute(30)
      .everyDays(1)
      .create();    
}
```

> Trigger works when there is only "sendEmails()" and "createTimeDrivenTriggers()" [Gsheet 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A9zec2A1cp9KSPWrhFsLRjgzwd6LW8yovMlnNMaTfE0/edit?usp=sharing)

[[image: only sendEmail and trigger2]

> If i put another Script "Dynamic Dropdown script" [Link](https://max-makhrov.medium.com/dependent-dropdown-lists-in-google-sheets-v2021-eab0bd1d7670)
> trigger wont run [Gsheet 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A_TvNB8iEtwx6ljDaCdQ0oSx5vr9zuhZAnlT2YppZfE/edit?usp=sharing)
> [image: Trigger wont run]

Comment: I belive your code is already doing what you want. What is the issue?

Comment: it doesnt auto send email, i need to click "run" on apps script. [here the spreedsheet] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A9zec2A1cp9KSPWrhFsLRjgzwd6LW8yovMlnNMaTfE0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To set up a function to run automatically on trigger

- Open the Apps Script editor
- Select from the dropdown menu the function that installs the trigger:

---

[image]

---

- Click on `Run`

The function to install the trigger needs to be run only once. After the trigger is created, the function `sendEmails` will be run automatically in the background at the time specified within the

Comment: done it, it only works when there no other script, meanwhile i need it to works with dynamic drop down script. i updated my original post

Comment: I am not sure either I understand your comment correctly - in case the problem still persists, make sure you do not have more than one function with the same name within the same Apps Script project.